# OpenGL do stuff when player don't look

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d

I'm facing this kind of problem: I would like to do something, when player isn't looking. For instance, like in SCP, move monster towards player. My question is: How can I check if player does see an object?

Comment: OpenGL is not a game engine. It just draws point, lines and triangles to the screen. Nothing more. There's no camera (just a view transform that acts as if it were a camera), there are no models, there is no internal scene representation. It's up to you to implement that check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the player is in control of the camera. The camera has a front vector. Using that front vector and the normal of the object, in this case the monster, you can find out whether he is looking or not.

You can take the dot product of the object normal and the front vector. If it is negative or equal to 0, the angle is perpendicular and the player can't see the object.

Comment: But when the monster won't be facing player, will this method still work?

Comment: Yes. You should basically just make the monster move towards the place    if angle is <= 0

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked for me :D